# Is id a python builtin function?

Tags: python, function, built-in

Would you please look at code below,

```
def getCrewListAll(self):
    """
    Set to crew list to all available crew
    """
    crew = getIdNumbers()
    return map(lambda cr: cr.id, crew)
```

What is the meaning of `cr.id` here, is `id` a builtin python function or?

Comment: There's a page in the Python docs called "Built-in Functions": http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id

Comment: This is specific to whatever library you have gotten this code from.

Comment: Have you examined--or are you able to examine--the code where `getIdNumbers()` is defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, the reference to `cr.id` is not a function call. Its accessing a **member attribute** of the `cr` variable, which is a placeholder for whatever the `crew` objects are.

`id` [is the name of a builtin function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id), yes. But there is no way to know if its being used under the hood in these objects without seeing the actual class definitions.

As an example... if this were, say, a django application, model instances have `id` member attributes that give you the database id of that record. Its part of the design of the class for that framework.

Even though I am assuming its an attribute... for all we know it could also be a [computed property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) which is similar to a method call that acts like an attribute. It could be doing more logic that it seems when looking at your example.

Lastly, since the `cr.id` could be anything, it could even be a method and the map is returning a lis of callables: cr.id()

Comment: @samy.vilar: I mentioned the possibility of properties. But also, its not a function call in terms of how the end user is applying it. It calls a function under the hood as per the design of properties.

Comment: @ms4py: You don't see the lambda wrapper function?

Comment: @ms4py `It needs to be callable for the map function, so it is a method. ` please clarify this, the map function simply takes in a function and applies it sequential to iterable object saving the return value nothing to do with properties or the like.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment, didn't see the lambda :) @jdi My downvote is locked, please make a small edit.

Answer (score 4):

`cr.id` isn't a builtin function (unless you've assigned it to be...), it's a normal member of the `cr` object there.

`id(cr)` would be an invocation of that builtin and would return the identity of `cr`.

Comment: But it isn't cr.id(). how come it doesn't have parantheses after it?

Comment: @alwbtc: Doesn't have parenthesis in your example? That would indicate that the **member attribute** of cr is `id`. Not a function

Comment: isn't a "method" a function? don't functions need parantheses after them?

Comment: @alwbtc: no one said it was a method. Just a "member". And yes in order to call a method or function you would use () but you can simply reference it without () and pass it around as a first class citizen. Its just an object.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real problem here is that you don't understand the code you have posted.
In this context you need to understand `map` and `lambda`.

[`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) is a function which applies a function to each element of a list and returns this as a list:

```
>>> def func(a):
...   return a * 2
...
>>> map(func, [1,2,3])
[2, 4, 6]
```

[`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) can be seen as a shortcut to create functions. The above could be written with `lambda`:

```
>>> func = lambda a: a * 2
>>> map(func, [1,2,3])
[2, 4, 6]
```

So what your code `map(lambda cr: cr.id, crew)` is doing: It returns a list of the id attribute from each of the objects in the list `crew`.

The problem is that this code is actually not pretty good. You can write the same function with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is much more intuitive:

```
def getCrewListAll(self):
    return [cr.id for cr in getIdNumbers()]
```

Comment: if he doesn't know maps do you think he knows list comprehension's?

Comment: No, but the linked tutorial is very good, especially for this topic. If the OP asks a question on SO, he should have the motivation to learn something new.

Comment: +1 for `he should have the motivation to learn something new.`

Answer (score 1):

there is a built in id function but may or may not be related to this, depending on the implementation of that object, either way id here is a member/property of that object.

If you are curious to see what kind of members/fields that object has you can do `dir(crew[0])` assuming its retuning at least one, and if its properly document you can also do this `help(crew[0].id)`

Comment: Answer is very unclear regarding the question. Showing `help(id)` is just confusing in this context.

Comment: normally people believe that a.id means just get that value and nothing else, right?, but if its a property then it isn't just get that value it could mean open a file, parse it, update it and lunch nuclear weapons well you get the idea ... ;)

Comment: I think it's confusing to say that it is related to the builtin `id()` function. (`crew_object.id = id(crew_object)` is a possibility, but there is no way of telling this from the code shown).

Comment: what I wanted to clarify is that while a.id may not look like a function call it actually is, if id is a property, `A().id()` `A().id` calls a function that returns an int and hence you get that error but if you have `@property def id(self): return lambda : id(self)` well you get the idea.

Comment: he did ask `is id a builtin python function or?`

Comment: @samy.vilar: ... but either way it is not directly related to the _builtin_ function `id()`. I believe the correct answer to this question is "Yes, `id()` is a builtin function. No, `cr.id` is not a builtin function."

Comment: well `we don't know that` it may or may not be like jdi said we `don't know unless we have the source` as such we can't/shouldn't make any assumptions.

Comment: As seen in above comments, the real problem is that he just does not understand `map` and/or `lambda` so explaining this would be the most helpful answer ;)

Comment: @ms4py why? the goal is the same you just want the ids or did you want something like this `return [cr.id for cr in getIdNumbers()]` but then I have to explain list comprehensions ...

Comment: LCs are really easy to learn/understand. The [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is very comprehensible. Never deprive a beginner the chance to learn something new (by posting a bad example).

Comment: Not to a beginner it scares the hell out of them, very few languages that are taught in school support such syntax, I think even more so then map which still resemble a functions call , but thats just my opinion. don't get me wrong I love them 3-4 times faster makes really concise code and just plain awesome.

Comment: @ms4py: I think its presumtuous to even assume the OP had anythig to do with the source code that was posted. If he didn't even write a map+lambda then there is no need to start teaching alternative. If he has said "maps and lamdas are confusing me" then it might be a good time to teach something new. As it stands, I think the OP just doesn't understand fundamentals enough to read this source.